# string to float error

Tags: python, list, floating-point

I'm trying to compare these two list:

```
 hexvalonsides = ['0.0', '0.3968708', '0.4124191', '0.5403639', '0.6150017', '0.8629506', '0.5946117', '0.4553542', '0.506171', '0.5026515', '0.0']
 hexvalonsides = ['0.2505809', '0.247734', '0.0', '0.169306', '0.06264286', '0.3082903', '0.4218272', '0.4553542', '0.506171', '0.5026515', '0.0']
```

using this method:

```
 for i in range(0, len(hexvalonsides)):
     for value in newhexvalonsides:
         if float(hexvalonsides[i]) - 0.5 <= value <= float(hexvalonsides[i]) + 0.05:
             count += 1
```

However, I keep getting an error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: .` I think it's because on the original file where I extracted the lists, I manually entered the `0.0` values for missing data. However, I'm not sure how I can correct for this here. Should I have inputed the `0.0`s differently? Any ideas?

Comment: Could you try running:  `import locale`
`locale._test()`

Comment: That's not possible. Are you sure you executed those two lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER:**

Check your input data.

The only way you can get the following error message:

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: .`

is when you have a string in the form `.`

Example:

```
print float('.')
```

Output:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: .
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

This is working on my side:

```
 hexvalonsides = ['0.0', '0.3968708', '0.4124191', '0.5403639', '0.6150017', '0.8629506', '0.5946117', '0.4553542', '0.506171', '0.5026515', '0.0']
 newhexvalonsides = ['0.2505809', '0.247734', '0.0', '0.169306', '0.06264286', '0.3082903', '0.4218272', '0.4553542', '0.506171', '0.5026515', '0.0']

 tmp = zip( [ float(x) for x in  hexvalonsides], 
            [ float(x) for x in  newhexvalonsides])

 count = sum(1 if x[0]-0.5 <= x[1] <= x[0]+0.05 else 0 for x in tmp)

 print count
```

Comment: Are you using the exact code or another input vectors?

Comment: I'm actually using multiple vector inputs (I'm running the above code in a for loop that creates the lists). However, when I scroll through the lists, there doesn't appear to be anything out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast `value` to a float as well:

```
for i in range(0, len(hexvalonsides)):
    for value in newhexvalonsides:
        if float(hexvalonsides[i]) - 0.5 <= float(value) <= float(hexvalonsides[i]) + 0.05:
            count += 1
```

Although you could do this more elegantly using `map`:

```
import operator

diff=map(operator.sub,map(float,hexvalonsides),map(float,newhexvalonsides))

print len(filter(lambda x:x>-0.5 and x<0.05,diff))
```

Comment: Even when I try to convert value to float, I get the same error.

Comment: Although it should not make a difference, what does `import locale;locale.localeconv()['decimal_point']` return ?

Comment: Are you sure you do not have a single `.` instead of `0.0`. That is the only way I can reproduce your error, other combinations either parse (e.g. `.0`) or give a different error (e.g. `0.0.0`)

Comment: hmm. I'll try to search for the single `.`

Comment: @Jaco it seems that we are thinking the same at the same time !! :)

Comment: @Jacoi `mport locale;locale.localeconv()['decimal_point']` returned  `"."`. Also, I couldn't find the single `.` in the file I inputed.